# Floating Point with 3 Digits after Point

Tags: android

Here is my button on click method. here a input 3 floating number. after calculation i want to show my result with 3 digit after point.It is shown in 3 text field. how can i do . ?

public void cal(View V){
        float dRa,dRb,dRc,z21,z12,z11,z22;

```
    dRa = Float.parseFloat(ra.getText().toString());
    dRb = Float.parseFloat(rb.getText().toString());
    dRc = Float.parseFloat(rc.getText().toString());

    //Result=dRa+dRb+dRc;

    z21 = ((dRa*dRb)/(dRa+dRb+dRc));
    z11=(dRa*(dRb+dRc)/(dRa+dRb+dRc));
    z22=(dRb*(dRa+dRc)/(dRa+dRb+dRc));

    Z21.setText("Z21 & Z12 are "+z21);

    Z11.setText("Z11' is "+z11);

    Z22.setText("Z22' is "+z22);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just did that today with 2 fraction digits. here's how I did it (though I used a double and not a float)

```
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(3);

    Z21.setText(format.format(Z21));
    Z11.setText(format.format(Z11));
    Z22.setText(format.format(Z22));
```

Comment: here show some problem

09-23 19:55:10.128: E/AndroidRuntime(30453): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3848)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18776)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)

Comment: This is still only a part of error stacktrace... :/

Comment: show can i show you the full error box . there limited number of character supports in comment box . ?

Comment: I would check the float values are ok, and maybe try replaceing `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()` with `NumberFormat.getInstance()`.

I for sure can't tell without the full class code

Comment: care to try replacing the floats to doubles?

also, is one of the floats null or anything? seems to crash on the line where you set the first z float: `z21 = ((dRa * dRb) / (dRa + dRb + dRc));`